Is a parental letter of consent required to leave or enter Kazakhstan for a mother traveling with her child?
If visiting Kazakhstan is it required to have a consent letter to leave and/or enter if minor child is traveling with only one parent? (Using visa-free entry permission).
Child is a US citizen, 14 years old, would be arriving from Mongolia (which does not have a consent letter requirement). Airline T&Cs do not mention such a requirement, and a customer service rep told me the airline doesn't require it for boarding "but Kazakhstan might require it, you should check". I have posted this question here concurrently with attempting to get an answer from the Kazakhstan embassy.

I think you need to give more information to get a reliable answer. Eg what is the child’s citizenship? How old (rules may be different for 16+). Where are you travelling from? If flying, which airline (its T&C may require a letter even if immigration rules do not).

@Traveller Child is a US citizen, 14 years old, would be arriving from Mongolia (which does not have a consent letter requirement). Airline T&Cs do not mention such a requirement, and a customer service rep told me the airline doesn't require it for boarding "but Kazakhstan might require it, you should check". I have posted this question here concurrently with attempting to get an answer from the Kazakhstan embassy.

it may well be that getting an answer from Kazakh authorities will be difficult or impossible. If the non-traveling parent is available and willing to sign a Consent letter, just getting the letter and carrying it might be easier and quicker.

And for a further presentation of these issues (same issues, but a different country), see this question.

I believe that the only party who may object here is the country of child's citizenship when they leave with one parent. 3rd party countries would not care as long as there's a legal guardian and there is no reason to suspect foul play.

@DavidRecallsMonica Unfortunately, the non-traveling parent isn't available in this case.
